# Android performance sqlite columns or raw json parsing

Tags: android, json, performance, sqlite

In terms of best practice and performance for binding data to list items in a CursorAdapter bind method, is there a major performance difference in parsing a json doc sourced from an sqlite table at time of binding compared to binding to table columns via a cursor . My json document is are simple name value pairs, no nested objects. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been developing Android for almost 5 years and I think the best way is to put the parsed JSON str and insert it in SQLite DB.

Because, when you just save your raw JSON str to DB, you will use a parser every time you fetch the data from DB, that costs more iteration time rather than do CRUD from the SQLite DB in which Android platform is designed to use.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, do you have a link to any reliable tests that demonstrate cursor calls are faster than simple json parsing. Fyi, I have edited the original question text.